# How to route the value of editable table cell to another method using Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I am using Django framework. Currently I have a table row whose cells are editable and the code is as follows:

```
<td><p align="center" contenteditable='true'>ABC</p><button>Edit</button></td>
```

Now my need is to edit the value of this cell to (say) *"XYZ"* from *"ABC"* and click on the button *"Edit"* and then it should redirect me to an api in the views.py file with the value of *"XYZ"*. So how can I achieve that ? Please help me as I am not much thorough with Django.

Should we use any javascript method or directly can I route the value *"XYZ"* to the api in views.py file?

Comment: This is possible if you already have an API built in the views.py, if you could share that, it would be easier to help you. Also, it interact with the api, you can use ```fetch``` in javascript using th method ```POST``` which will allow you to post data to the API in views.py which will make it easy to manipulate this data. If you are looking for help on how to make the API itself, do let me know.

Comment: In the views.py file, I have an api created as follows to receive the value to be updated to: 

def update_result(request, val):
..

Does it answer your question? Please help me to proceed. 
Thanks.